# Managing SSH keys for Capistrano deployments from within a Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, docker, ssh, capistrano

I currently use Docker Compose (with a Dockerfile based on the ruby:2.4.1 image, which I understand to be Debian) to run tests in a Ruby on Rails app.

I'd like to deploy from within the container as well. However, the deployment (from within the Docker container) fails when it comes to accessing the GitLab server from the remote server:

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as appuser@app.staging: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

From what I can tell, the SSH agent is not running in the container and so is not being forwarded to the remote server, but I can't seem to fix it.

If I log into the container with `docker-compose run app bash` and run `ssh app.staging`, it connects successfully and even uses the user defined in `/root/.ssh/config`, so clearly the config is being read.

`AgentForwarding yes` is set in `/root/.ssh/config` in the container (and not overridden in `/etc/ssh/config`), and `AllowAgentForwarding yes` is set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote server.

I have tried adding `eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa` to `/etc/profile` or `/root/.bashrc` on the container but neither of them seem to be called by Capistrano or by Bash. Running these commands manually fixes the problem, so I think this is the root of the issue.

All of the results I'm finding for problems similar to this are about SSHing *into* the Docker container, and that's not my problem. Is there anything else to try? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: did you also tried to login as appuser, so `ssh appuser@app.staging`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that services aren't initialised until after the container is run. You could create an entrypoint to run specific commands before cmd is run.

You could take a look at how jenkins ssh-slaves are done from [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-slave)

In your case, you may want to have the server's entrypoint file to run `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

Then your client's entrypoint file would run `eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh username@server`.

Passwords could be passed as secrets then assigned to variables. `SSH_ASKPASS="$(cat /run/secrets/password)"`

Comment: The server doesn't yet run Docker so this is just for the client, but starting the SSH agent in the entrypoint worked! I had a script that waited for services before running a command, so I moved that to the ENTRYPOINT. Thanks a lot!